# IP Camera Can't Access From Web Interface

Tags: http

My friend setup the ip camera.. but when he goes to access the ip camera from web interface search using the ip on my browser..nothing is found.
**Does anyone know why or have any suggestions why this does not work?**

Comment: What is camera IP? What is network configuration? Is his PC in the same network as camera? Have you tried ``http://<camera_ip>``?

Answer (score 1):

Your friend should verify that the IP camera is visible on his network.  The best way to do this is to log into the local network router and look for the list of "DHCP Clients".  This will normally be in the Advanced, Local Network, or LAN section of a consumer grade router.  Typically a camera will give its name in the list of DHCP clients.

Once you find out the IP address of the camera, try using that address to connect to the camera's user interface.